# How to add a vertical swipe gesture to iPhone app for all screens?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, xamarin.ios, gesture

I'd like to add a gesture to my app so when the user swipes vertically it triggers a method to do something.  The swipe can be up or down.  I've never done anything with gestures so this is my first use of a gesture other than what is included in a UITableView for deleting rows.

The other problem is that most of my screens are UITableViews so the user could be simply scrolling the UITableView.  So I am wondering if I could use a two finger swipe (vertical) to detect the gesture to run the code vs. a single finger swipe to scroll the UITableView?

Thank you in advance.

Neal

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This goes in ApplicationDidLaunch:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedScreen:)] autorelease];
swipeGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    swipeGesture.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown);

[window addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
```

then implement

```
- (void) swipedScreen:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipeGesture {
   // do stuff
}
```

Use the documentation for [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer) and [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISwipeGestureRecognizer).

Also if you wish to detect the direction of the swipe you will have to setup two separate gesture recognizers. You can not get the direction of a swipe from a swipe gesture recognizer, only the directions it is registered to recognize.

Comment: Found a problem - when I rotate my device the swipe "vertical" gesture does not take into account the orientation.  So if you create a vertical (DirectionUp/Down) swipe and rotate the device to landscape you have to swipe horizontally now.  Any suggestions to resolve this?

Comment: sure try removing the gesture recognizer and readding them after the rotation. You can use the UIView instance method `gestureRecognizers` to loop through them and remove them. ie `for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.view)`

Comment: @mackross i want swap multiple view up and down so how can implement say me plz....???

Comment: what is `window` here in `[window addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];` ..?

Answer (score 0):

In swift 4.0, that goes on the method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of the AppDelegate:

```
let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipedScreen(swipeGesture:)))
swipeGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
swipeGesture.direction = [UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up,  UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down]
window?.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
```

And the action:

```
@objc func swipedScreen(swipeGesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    Swift.print("hy")
}
```

Comment: UISwipeGestureRecognizer does not have a numberOfTouchesRequired

Comment: @dre_84w934 actually it does, please check link below. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer/1619182-numberoftouchesrequired