# iOS global method

Tags: iphone, ios, gesture, swipe-gesture, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm doing an application where I want the user to be able to use swipe gestures to push and pop view controllers. I will be using a swipe gesture recogniser to achieve this. My question is, is there any way I could implement the recognisers globally as opposed to implementing it in every single view controller? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a vertical swipe gesture to iPhone app for all screens?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640000/how-to-add-a-vertical-swipe-gesture-to-iphone-app-for-all-screens)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a category, and apply it to UIViewController. Item 11 [here](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/) clearly explains how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the gesture recogniser to your `UIWindow`, as detailed in [How to add a vertical swipe gesture to iPhone app for all screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640000/how-to-add-a-vertical-swipe-gesture-to-iphone-app-for-all-screens)