# Add vertical two finger swipe gesture to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift

According to [How to add a vertical swipe gesture to iPhone app for all screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640000/how-to-add-a-vertical-swipe-gesture-to-iphone-app-for-all-screens), I add a two finger swipe down gesture to `window`, which works fine on normal pages throughout the whole app. But it fails on the page has `UIScrollView` (like UITableViewController). When I swipe down **with two fingers** on `UIScrollView`, it just scrolls it as normal. If I swipe from `UINavigationBar` that above `UIScrollView`, it works fine again.

The ideal result is that I can scroll tableview by one finger normally, and call some method by swiping page with two fingers without scrolling tableview. This is used in TweetBot to switch dark mode, works perfectly.

According to Apple's document: [Using Responders and the Responder Chain to Handle Events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/using_responders_and_the_responder_chain_to_handle_events), I think I understand how the Responder Chain works, so I want to ask `UIScrollView` to ignore the two fingers swipe gesture so that it can pass this event to `UIWindow`. But I can't figure out how to:

I tried to implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`'s `func gestureRecognizer(_:, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer:)` from Apple's [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/preferring_one_gesture_over_another), or override `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_)` by inherit `UITableView`. But all didn't work.

Any solutions or advice is welcomed.

### Update - Final Solution

I simplified joern's solution and here is.

In `AppDelegate`

```
// It's not necessary to keep a reference to gesture unless you want to do something further.
lazy var gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(twoFingerDidSwipe(recognizer:)))
    gesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2
    gesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2
    return gesture
}()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    gesture.delegate = AppDelegate
    window.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    return true
}

@objc func twoFingerDidSwipe(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let swipeThreshold: CGFloat = 50

    if recognizer.state == .changed { // 1
      switch recognizer.translation(in: window).y { // 2
      case ...(-swipeThreshold):
        print("Swipe Up")
        recognizer.state = .cancelled // 3
      case swipeThreshold...:
        print("Swipe Down")
        recognizer.state = .cancelled
      default:
        break
      }
    }
}
```

And

```
extension AppDelegate: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

Some explanations about differences from joern's solution:

1. Only `recognizer.state == .change` is concerned.
2. `recognizer.translation(in:)`'s parameter should be `window` so that I can do nothing about particular VCs.
3. After triggering some methods by this recognizer, it should be cancelled to prevent from triggering them continually.

And It's unnecessary to do anything about any particular VC.

With this, two-finger swipe gesture works fine on both normal VC and scroll VC.

Comment: Please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711395/two-finger-swipe-in-uiscrollview-for-ipad-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to your window, keep a reference to it, so you can access it later via the `AppDelegate`:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var twoFingerSwipeDownRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let twoFingerSwipeDownRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didRecognizeTwoFingerSwipeDown))
        twoFingerSwipeDownRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
        twoFingerSwipeDownRecognizer.direction = .down
        window?.addGestureRecognizer(twoFingerSwipeDownRecognizer)
        self.twoFingerSwipeDownRecognizer = twoFingerSwipeDownRecognizer

        return true
    }

    @objc func didRecognizeTwoFingerSwipeDown(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        print("SWIPE DOWN")
    }
}
```

Then, in the `UIViewController` that contains the `UITableView` (or `UIScrollView`) you have to call `require(toFail:)` on the UITableView's pan gesture recognizer:

```
func enableTwoFingerSlideDown() {
    guard
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
        let twoFingerGestureRecognizer = appDelegate.twoFingerSwipeDownRecognizer
        else {
            return
        }
    tableView.panGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: twoFingerGestureRecognizer)
}
```

Now the two finger down gesture works over a `UITableView`.

**UPDATE**

Because a swipe is a discrete gesture the solution above might not be the perfect solution. When you scroll down slowly with **one** finger you will notice that the `UITableView` will not scroll down instantly. There is a short delay because the `UITableView's` `UIPanGestureDelagate` has to wait until the (Two Finger) SwipeDelegate has failed. And that takes some time.

A better solution might be to use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to recognize a two finger pan and then disable the scrolling on the `UITableView` while the user is panning using two fingers.

That could be achieved like this:

**In your AppDelegate:**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var twoFingerPanRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let twoFingerSwipeDownRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didRecognizeTwoFingerPan))
        twoFingerSwipeDownRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2
        twoFingerSwipeDownRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2
        twoFingerPanRecognizer?.delegate = self
        window?.addGestureRecognizer(twoFingerSwipeDownRecognizer)
        self.twoFingerPanRecognizer = twoFingerSwipeDownRecognizer

        return true
    }

    @objc func didRecognizeTwoFingerPan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let tableView = recognizer.view as? UITableView
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            tableView?.isScrollEnabled = false
        case .changed:
            let swipeThreshold: CGFloat = 50
            switch recognizer.translation(in: nil).y {
            case ...(-swipeThreshold):
                print("Swipe UP")
                recognizer.isEnabled = false
            case swipeThreshold...:
                print("Swipe DOWN")
                recognizer.isEnabled = false
            default:
                break
            }
        case .cancelled, .ended, .failed, .possible:
            tableView?.isScrollEnabled = true
            recognizer.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**In your ViewController:**

```
func enableTwoFingerSlideDown() {
        guard
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
            let twoFingerGestureRecognizer = appDelegate.twoFingerPanRecognizer
            else {
                return
            }
        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(twoFingerGestureRecognizer)
    }
```

You have to take the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` from the `AppDelegate` and add it to the `UITableView`. Otherwise this won't work. Just remember to add it back to the `UIWindow` before this `UIViewController` is dismissed.

With this solution the normal scrolling behavior of the `UITableView` remains unchanged.

Comment: It works. The point is `require(toFail:)`. When Apple is saying "shouldRequireFailure" in [the document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/preferring_one_gesture_over_another) , it only mentions UIGestureRecognizerDelegate's method, instead of UITableView recognizers'. I read many articles and no one mentions recognizers' method itself... Thank you so much!

Comment: I just found out that `UIScrollView` exposes its `UIPanGestureRecognizer` via the `panGestureRecognizer` property. So you don't have to iterate over all gesture recognizer but can call `require(toFail:)` directly on the table view's pan gesture recognizer. I updated the answer.

Comment: I have to say this update is AWESOME. But on the normal page that doesn't have scrollView, this panGesture dosen't work even this page is the initial ViewController of my app (so not about "add it back to the UIWindow"). I tested and found that on normal viewController, when I swipe with two fingers, `didRecognizeTwoFingerPan` will be called but never reach `case ...(-swipeThreshold):`, always to `default: break`. I can remain old `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to `window` to solve it although.

Comment: I upload the final solution.