# Two finger swipe down to return to menu

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am creating an app where the first screen is a main menu. One button goes to a settings page and is in a nav controller so has a 'back' button. Another option opens the camera for aug reality. I want to enable the ability to recognise a two finger swipe down which returns to the main menu.

Quite new to this latest version of Swift so am in need of help!

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908002/add-vertical-two-finger-swipe-gesture-to-uiscrollview

Comment: It's more about swipe gestures. So, you can play with **UISwipeGestureRecognizer**

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an iOS question than a Swift question.

Take a look at the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` class. You can configure a swipe gesture recognizer to require a 2 finger swipe.

The thing about a swipe gesture recognizer is that it is a "one-shot" gesture. It doesn't report anything until it detects a swipe, and then it triggers your action.

A swipe gesture recognizer won't let you scroll down slowly and see the main menu starting to appear. If you want that effect you'd have to instead use a 2 finger pan gesture recognizer and add some of your own custom code to handle the intermediate scrolling and the logic to decide that the gesture crossed the threshold from a scroll to a swipe.

A quick Google search found this link that explains using swipe gesture recognizers:

https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Identifying_Gestures_using_iOS_8_Gesture_Recognizers#Recognizing_Swipe_Gestures

(for your case you'd want to add `swipeRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2 and change your swipe direction to` .down`)

Modifying the code from that example:

```
let swipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
             action: #selector(ViewController.swipeDetected(_:)))
swipeRecognizer.direction = .down
swipeRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRecognizer)
```

(Although the action signature looks wrong to me. The sender for a UIGestureRecognizer is the gesture recognizer, not the view controller. I'd expect the init call to look like this instead:

```
let swipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
             action: #selector(ViewController.swipeDetected as 
        (UITapGestureRecognizer) -> () -> ()))
```

### EDIT:

The setting you need to change for a 2 finger swipe is numberOfTouchesRequired, not numberOfTapsRequired. I fixed the code above, as well as the action signature.

Comment: Thank you. The "one-shot" gesture is all I need. It's just to return to the main VC.